Get method not displaying the data on browser and postman
I was trying to create API with Java. While using the get method I'm not receiving the JSON data. It's only displaying closed braces as response.
I'm attaching the code and output below. Any suggestions might be helpful.
Controller
@GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getProducts() {
        return getProductService.execute(null);
    }

GetProductService Class
public class GetProductService implements Query<Void, List<Product>> {

    public GetProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;


    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> execute(Void input) {
        List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(products);
    }
}

Query Interface
public interface Query <I, O> {
    ResponseEntity<O> execute(I input);
}

ProductRepository Intergface
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {
}

I have tried to print the data on the terminal and it worked but still don't know why it didnt's show on the browser and postman.

Did you ensure that the definition of Product class matches your database (repository) schema?

Yes and it work just fine on the terminal.

I hope you are doing well ,
it is more likely your response is too large
for simulation purposes i have built a large JSON with random values bigger than postman

Max response size

and after calling the API there was nothing as a response , and browser can not handle it too.
Some possible solutions :
1-Paginate the Response to break it down smaller pieces , for example :
@GetMapping("/data")
public ResponseEntity<List<Data>> getData(@RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    Page<Data> dataPage = dataRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(dataPage.getContent());
}

2-Truncate the response as below
@GetMapping("/data")
public ResponseEntity<?> getData() {
    List<Data> data = fetchData(); // Your method to fetch data
    if (data.size() > MAX_SIZE) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(data.subList(0, MAX_SIZE)); // Return truncated data
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
}

3-Maximize the response size of postman

Thank you so much for your answer but turn out the problem was because lombok didn't work on the newest version of intellij so i just have to write Product class manually. Again thank you for your answer and this might be helpful in the future.
